# IBM MQ Log write integrity

Tags: ibm-mq

In the Queue manager object we have a parameter under log section to define the log write integrity. What is the difference between *SingleWrite*, *DoubleWrite* and *TripleWrite* in IBM MQ log write integrity ? Please explain in detail.

Comment: This answer might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296196/singlewrite-vs-triplewrite

Comment: going [here](http://bit.ly/1PaFRm1), the first two results will take you to the ibm manual where the difference is explained with details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LogWriteIntegrity` is all about how the queue manager logger writes partial 4KB pages. Unless you are **absolutely certain** that your file system provides atomically written pages under **all circumstances** you should leave it at the default setting of `TripleWrite`. The option to set anything other than `TripleWrite` only exists because of a possible performance enhancement, however since partial pages should be rare with a queue manager with a good amount of concurrent work going on, it's not a big area for performance improvement, and a better way to improve the performance of your queue manager is to increase concurrency rather than the risks associated with changing this setting.

There is a very useful blog post from MQ Development that you should read. You can find it here: [LogWriteIntegrity.... should I pick SingleWrite or TripleWrite?](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/Bitesize_Blogging_LogWriteIntegrity_should_I_pick_SingleWrite_or_TripleWrite)