# Why does IBM MQ do triple write in the recovery log?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ibm-mq, wal

As far as I know, IBM uses triple write to persistent recovery log with steps as below:

1. assuming the page(4k) already has 1k data in it
2. loads the page from disk first
3. modify the page to add contents(3k) and write it to some other place
4. write the page to disk
5. if the page was broke, then it can restore it from the backup when recover from power down.

It's used to prevent partial write as claimed, cause it might break the original data in the page if the machine crash when writing data directly and the FS/disk don't support atomic write.

My question is why not just write append only log like WAL instead of inplace update?

Comment: It only needs to use triple write for a partial log page write.  This would not be the case on a busy queue manager.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I am still confused why not do append only for a partial log page write?

Comment: It was designed 20+ years ago and based on db2. Why does how a closed source COTS software handles partial writes matter to you?  If it works and works good you either use it or not.

Comment: I am just trying to figure out the background of the design in case there are some corner case which I can learn from and compare it with Kafka which I don't think has handled it.

And IBＭ MQ has released new version every year, I don't think they will keep this design without a reason.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296196/singlewrite-vs-triplewrite

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/Bitesize_Blogging_LogWriteIntegrity_should_I_pick_SingleWrite_or_TripleWrite?lang=en